# How to resolve Inteliji Maven Configuration error for cucumberOutput?

Tags: selenium, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

There is an error in pom.xml with Inteliji, same pom.xml is working fine in Eclipse ,

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>Automation</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}cucumber/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Error  is at  `<cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}cucumber/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>`

**Error message :**

Element cucumberOutput is not allowed here

Comment: Show full plugin config

Comment: @AlexeyR. Updated the question , Thanks

Comment: Please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version **5.6.0** *no longer uses* the `<cucumberOutput>` tag for the configuration.

It has been replaced with:

```
<inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory> <!-- this is where the cucumber.json files is saved -->
<jsonFiles>
   <param>cucumber.json</param> <!-- the name/regex of the cucumber report json file -->
</jsonFiles>
```

Here is an example of my configuration:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>execution</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <projectName>App-Under-Test</projectName>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
             <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
             <jsonFiles>
                <param>cucumber-*.json</param>
             </jsonFiles>
             <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
             <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
             <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
             <buildNumber>1</buildNumber>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```